# How to build php cURL like as cURL command line

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon CloudDrive
For API: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes

When I test Upload file to clouddrive using cURL command line, everything is OK. Like:

> curl -v -X POST --form 'metadata={"name":"test.pdf","kind":"FILE"}'
>   --form 'content=@test.pdf' 'https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/nodes?localId=linkvipdata&suppress=deduplication'
>   --header "Authorization: Bearer Atza|IQEBLjAsAhQsfI0yWoBK-FYhjUGJ1DBP1..."
>   --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"

But PHP is not OK and always return Error 500 ({"message":"Internal failure"})

PHP Code is:

```
$url='https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/nodes?localId=testupload&suppress=deduplication';
$file=realpath('test.pdf');
$fields[]=array(
    'metadata'=>array(
        'name'=>'testupload',
        'kind'=>'FILE'
    )
);
$fields[]=array(
    'content'=>'@'.$file
);
$fields_string = json_encode($fields);
$headers=array();
$headers[]='Authorization: Bearer '.$auth;
$headers[]='Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
$headers[]='Host: content-na.drive.amazonaws.com';
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);  
$httpstatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
print_r($result);
//print_r($httpstatus);
curl_close($ch);
```

How to build PHP cURL from cURL command Line as above?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about PHP but don't you replace *metadata* in $fields[] with *content*?

Also $fields is not **JSON**, it must be **multipart/form-data**. But value of metadata key in $fields should contain JSON with *name*, *parent* and *kind*.

And just in case, for CURL $file should be path to file, not content.